# Hide element based on the value of select name option?

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdo, smarty

I want get the value from the select name and when the value will be somthing, take some action. All value are save in pdo db.

Html: `<header>Something</header>`

Code:

```
<select name='name_of_select'>

<option value='on'>On</option>
<option value='off'>Off</option>

</select>
```

Ex. When the value will be set to **on**, hide element **header**. The value I getting from the db. And the value present `{$option_selected_value}` in smarty template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will be help you

```
$('select[name=name_of_select]').change(function(){
if($(this).val()=='on')
    $('header').show();
    else
    $('header').hide();

});
```

Fiddle [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/G2cNZ/)

Answer (score -2):

This will do what you are asking, but it relies on you adding IDs to the select and the header elements.  If you're not going to be able to do that then please post some real markup and I'll fix this to suit :)

```
$("#selectID").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "on") {
        $("#headerID").show();
    } else {
        $("#headerID").hide();
    }
});
```